# Calling preocedure by passing DB Link Dynamically

Tags: oracle, dynamic-sql

How to pass db link dynamically while calling a procedure?

Execute immediate will work or we need to use dbms_sql?

For DBMS_SQL i seen it used mostly with curosrs :(

Can any one help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.  Something like

```
DECLARE
  l_dblink_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'YourDBLink';
  l_sql_stmt    VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  l_sql_stmt := 'BEGIN procedure_name@' || l_dblink_name || ' (:1, :2); END;';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt
    USING 17, 42;
END;
```

assuming that your procedure takes two parameters and you want to call it with parameter values 17 and 42.