# Receive a db link name as a variable in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following function in *PLSQL* which connects remotely to different Database Links to change passwords:

```
FUNCTION fun_change_password(DB_LINK_VARIABLE varchar2)
    RETURN binary_integer IS

    jobid binary_integer;

  BEGIN
      dbms_job.submit@DB_LINK_VARIABLE (jobid,'begin execute immediate ''alter user MYUSER identified by mypassw''; end;');
      COMMIT;
      RETURN jobid;
  END;
```

My goal is to specify which DB Link to use sending its name in a varchar2 variable called *DB_LINK_VARIABLE*. But when I compile this into a package, the parser sends me an error:

> PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'DB_LINK_VARIABLE'

Obviously, I pre-configured and tested all my datalinks and works perfectly.

**How can I use variable 'DB_LINK_VARIABLE' into this code?**

Comment: I would be surprised if you could to this.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Actually, there is a way to do this using 'dynamic SQL' and SYS_REFCURSOR data-type, but I found a problem with quotation. Check this example:   

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pro_test (pv_dblink VARCHAR2)
IS
  emp_refcur      SYS_REFCURSOR;
  empno VARCHAR2(20);
  ename VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
   OPEN emp_refcur FOR 'SELECT empno, ename FROM emp@'||pv_dblink;
   LOOP
   FETCH emp_refcur into empno,ename;
   EXIT WHEN  emp_refcur%NOTFOUND;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee no: '||empno||'/ Employee name: '||ename);
   END LOOP;
END;`

Comment: I just found this.. Justin's answer for this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009277/calling-preocedure-by-passing-db-link-dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm) by executing an anonymous PL/SQL block.

Below is a simple example where I execute [dbms_utility.get_time](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_util.htm#ARPLS73253) function over a database link.

```
$ cat so35.sql
declare
  function remote_time(p_dblink in varchar2) return number is
    v_time number; 
  begin  
    execute immediate
      'begin :time := dbms_utility.get_time@' || p_dblink || '; end;'
    using out v_time;
    return v_time;
  end;
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('time = ' || remote_time('foo'));
end;
/


SQL> select dbms_utility.get_time as local, dbms_utility.get_time@foo as remote from dual;

     LOCAL     REMOTE
---------- ----------
  77936814 1546395927

SQL> @so35.sql
time = 1546396850

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I see.. You are right, so, the user can just make a minor change in his code to make it work! Thanks for letting me know my mistake!

Answer (score 1):

```
PLS-00352: Unable to access another database 'DB_LINK_VARIABLE'
```

Error message shows, oracle is looking for a db link called `DB_LINK_VARIABLE` instead of the value associated to it.

You may need to do a check on variable, and make the hardcoding of the db link , instead of using a bind variable for it.!

`Functions` are compiled code in DB, so I guess oracle would do a semantic check on this during compilation itself, rather than doing it in runtime.

If it was just a `SQL` call to remote db, `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` would have been used. Since it is `PL/SQL` there is no way for it, but for having multiple `IF` conditions, to validate the variable name, and making the full name in your `PL/SQL` block.

Comment: The explanation of `PLS-00352` is correct, but the conclusion that this can't be done with dynamic SQL is incorrect !